# Why "duplicate key error" when inserting subdocument arrays?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, subdocument

I have a Mongoose Schema in which I use subdocuments. Their definitions are:

```
const vraagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  vraagNummer: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 1
  },
  vraagTekst: {
    type: String,
    minLength: 1,
    required: true
  },
  waarde: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 1
  }
}, { collection: 'vragen' });

const checkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  checkID: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 2
  },
  sessieNummer: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 1
  },
  omschrijving: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  vragen: {
    type: [vraagSchema]
  },
  logData: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: ''
  }
});
checkSchema.index({ sessieNummer: 1, checkID: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

Now, when I insert 1 Check item with an empty array for the "vragen" field ("vragen" is Dutch for "questions"), there is no problem.
But when I try to insert another Check item, with slightly different field values (so that it is unique), but also with an empty array "[]" as value for "vragen", I get an error: "MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: demastermind_test.checks index: vragen.vraagNummer_1 dup key: { : null }".

Why is an empty array leading to a duplicate key error? And how can I prevent this?

I then checked what happened if I inserted Check items with non-empty arrays. So I inserted two checks with different field values (so they are unique), where 1 item has a "vragen" array with on "vraag" item in it, and 1 item has a "vragen" array with two "vraag" items in them (where I made sure that the two items had different "vraagNummer" waardes).
And that also leads to the exact same duplicate key error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem fixed. Apparently somewhere when I started working on this, I used an incorrect schema definition (or something), and that error got 'stuck' in de Collection.

I solved the problem by deleting the whole Collection (it currently is a test collection, so that wasn't a problem), and now it works as it should be.

Comment: Yeah, as silly  as it seems same  here. I deleted the entire collection. It was the only 1️⃣, so it removed the database. I went back to Atlas and created it from scratch and then **same** code worked! ⁉️